# Getting the error "Grader.java: Line 10: class expected" but not sure what the problem is, I've gone through it multiple times but cannot tell

Tags: java, arrays

The assignment was to write a method that returns the row and column of the string "needle" in a 2D array of strings, and that there would either be one or zero of these "needle" strings.
I did this but I'm getting an error at line 10 (return "row: " + i + ", column: " + j;) saying "class expected", have no idea why since it's a simple return statement? Any help would be greatly appreciated<3

```
public String needleInHaystack(String[][] haystack) 
{

boolean isNeedle = false;

for (int i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < haystack[].length; j++) {
        if (haystack[i][j].equals("needle")) {
            isNeedle = true;
            return "row: " + i + ", column: " + j;
        }
    }
}
if (isNeedle == false) {
    return "none";
}

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `for (int j = 0; j < haystack[i].length; j++) {` ?

Comment: Thanks so much I cant believe that I missed that